# Parse a string of a linear equation into a vector of the coefficients (Python)

Tags: python, string, sympy

I am looking for a **Python** solution that takes a string of a linear equation and outputs a vector of the coefficients.

To make things simple for the start, assume I have a set of equations:

- given in string form
- each with no more than 4 elements
- all are linear
- in all of them `x` appears only once

then I would like to get a vectorized representation where

- the first element is the `x` coefficient
- other elements are other coefficients in the equation (not evaluated, but as they are), as if they appeared on the other side of the equation as `x`
- zeros to complete the 4-d vector

I give here several input-output equations to get a sense of some of the challenges:

- `'2*x+3=2+5' => [2, -3, 2, 5]`
- `'88/8=x'    =>       [8, 88, 0, 0]`
- `'74=(35+18)+3*x'     =>    [3, 74, -35, -18]`
- `'((4+4)*6)=x']      =>       [1/6, 4, 4, 0]`
- `'-X=(91.0+88.0)'      =>     [-1, 91, 88, 0]`
- `'X=(30.0/10.0)'       =>      [10, 30, 0, 0]`
- `'0.16 + 0.41 = 2*x - 0.08'     =>     [2, 0.16, 0.41, 0.08]`
- `'(0.25 + 0.37)*2 = x'     =>     [1/2, 0.25, 0.37, 0]`

> I started coding a "brute force" solution that is highly rigorous and tedious, stumbled several times along the way, and figured there must be a nicer and more clever way to do this...
>
> - I am using the `sympy` package, which makes things a bit easier. With `sympify` and `formula.split` and such I am able to extract the `x` coefficient and the result of the equation (although *I really don't care about the result, but only the vector representation*)
> - I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076935/function-to-translate-linear-equations-into-matrix-form-in-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093264/parse-coefficient-of-an-linear-equation) but they are both in different languages, and not quite what I am looking for.
>
> Sooo, anyone has any idea how to do it in Python?
>
> Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may get you going in the right direction:

```
>>> def peq(s):
...     from sympy import S
...     l, r = t = S(s, evaluate=False)
...     free = t.free_symbols
...     assert len(free) == 1
...     x = free.pop()
...     if r.has(x):
...         l, r = r, l
...     assert not r.has(x)
...     assert l.has(x)
...     assert not l.diff(x).free_symbols
...     v = []
...     v.append(l.coeff(x))
...     v.append(-(l.subs(x, 0)))
...     if not r.is_Add:
...         v.extend([r, S.Zero])
...     else:
...         assert r.is_Add and len(r.args) == 2
...         v.extend(r.args)
...     return v
>>> peq('2*x+3,-2+5/3')
[2,−3,−2,5/3]
>>> peq('2*x+3,-2')
[2,−3,−2,0]
>>> peq('x,-2')
[1,0,−2,0]
```

Comment: Looks great, yet I don't understand what is `S`, and also, is `x` supposed to be `'x'`?. Thanks!

Comment: `S` is the shorthand for the `sympify` function that turns a string into SymPy objects. I'll try to update the function.

Comment: OK, you might want to test that 'x' actually appears; what I have above will work with anything that looks like a variable, e.g. `y` or `the_variable`.

Comment: Had to make a couple of semantic changes to make it work, but this is definitely along the lines of what I was looking for. Thanks!